# React HTMLtoJSX does not convert curly brackets

Tags: javascript, converters, reactjs

I am experiencing a problem with the HTMLtoJSX converter (npm: htmltojsx), the same converter as officially displayed on https://facebook.github.io/react/html-jsx.html.

The HTML-code `<div>{</div>` is compiled to the following JSX-code:

```
<div>{</div>
```

The JSX code fails with the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: embedded: Unexpected token (7:18)
   5 | var Hello = React.createClass({
   6 |   render: function() {
>  7 |     return <div>{</div>;
     |                   ^
   8 |   }
   9 | });
```

Test: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/28714/

Does anyone know a solution for the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JSX curly brackets are used to wrap javascript expressions. You can display bracket like this:

```
return <div>{'{'}</div>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply! Your solution is correct.

It appears to be a bug in the official HTML to JSX converter:

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5910

The author has promised to fix it.